# chrome new version exception with jqplot double click

Tags: google-chrome, exception, click, double, jqplot

I've got an automatic update for chrome, now I have version 36.0.1985.125. Previously I had 35.0.1916.
I'm suspecting that it's the new chrome version that invokes exceptions in my chart. I've searched hours thinking that the problem is in my code, but than I saw it also occurs here:
http://www.jqplot.com/tests/zooming.php
try zooming the chart, than press double click on it to zoom-out. Everything will work fine- you'll zoom-out, but an exception will be thrown in your console.
I get this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'collapse' on 'Selection': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.
```

Everything still working fine though, but it's still get my annoying. why this is happening?
Am I correct that it's the chrome version? I could not find any other reason.  try comparing versions if you can.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a change in Chrome behaviour due to this commit:
https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?revision=172106&view=revision

Collapse can no longer be called without arguments.

The cursor plugin has been patched earlier. If you use the plugin from this ticket in bitbucket it should be fixed:
https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/347/cursor-plugin-sel-collapse-is-a-syntax

Comment: In my case (Chrome 62, jqPlot 1.0.9) there was easy fix: by adding `style="-webkit-user-select: none;"` to `div` element with plot.